# Select row from a table that does not exist in other table

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to select a row that exist in the images table but not in the images_viewed table. They both share the same name.

This is the code I am using. it works, but it making my website very slow.

```
$next = $mysqli->query("SELECT `name` FROM `images` WHERE `name` NOT IN (SELECT `name` FROM `images_viewed` WHERE `ip` = '$ip') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
        if($next->num_rows == 1){   
            $fetch_next = $next->fetch_assoc();
            $next_name = $fetch_next['name'];
        }
```

how can I fix this code? is there a better select statement that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT images.name FROM images 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN images_viewed 
    ON images.name = images_viewed.name 
  WHERE images_viewed.ANY_OTHER_FIELD IS NULL AND images_views.ip = {$ip}
```

Comment: This SQL is correct, but the performance would be further improved by adding an indexed column in the `images` table to track whether the image has been viewed. Then, you are making an indexed query against one table, instead of a join or subquery.

Comment: @Zhube, you are right, but OP would have to map viewed images by IPs, in a N:M relationship table.

Comment: didn't catch the IP part in the OP. The INNER JOIN in that situation may be more performant, and the database would be more normalized.

Comment: With `INNER JOIN` he will only get images that were viewed, but he wants to get the ones that where NOT viewed.

Comment: That's true. I wasn't considering tracking the views by IP with my original response, just whether they had been viewed or not. Hence, the suggestion to use a flag to filter against. :)